# Getting values of selected table rows in bootstrap using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I'm using bootstrap table. In that I want to get `Item ID` value/values of selected table rows after clicking `'Add to cart'` button present on same page.

Table code:

```
<table data-toggle="table" id="table-style" data-row-style="rowStyle" data-url="tables/data2.json"  data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc" data-single-select="false" data-click-to-select="true" data-maintain-selected="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
      <th data-field="id" >Item ID</th>
      <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Product Name</th>
      <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Actual Price</th>
      <th data-field="discount_price" data-sortable="true">Discount Price</th>
      <th data-field="stock_avail" data-sortable="true">Stock Available</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#add_cart").click(function()
   {
      //foreach selected row retrieve 'Item ID' values in array;
      //call ajax for otherpage.php?arr='Item ID array';
   });
});
```

As I'm new in bootstrap I'm trying to tackle this but not getting proper solution anybody please advise me this.

[image]

Comment: How the `tr td` data look like?

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali- please see my edited question.

Comment: Opss sorry, once again, can you sure the HTML structure of table rows, wanna see how the HTML rendered. Just  a few line enough

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali- I uses bootstrap table plugins for table.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just use the `check.bs.table` and `uncheck.bs.table` events to collect your checked rows.

[**BS-Table Basic Events**](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/#events)

Here is an example:

```js
var checkedRows = [];

$('#eventsTable').on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
  checkedRows.push({id: row.id, name: row.name, forks: row.forks});
  console.log(checkedRows);
});

$('#eventsTable').on('uncheck.bs.table', function (e, row) {
  $.each(checkedRows, function(index, value) {
    if (value.id === row.id) {
      checkedRows.splice(index,1);
    }
  });
  console.log(checkedRows);
});

$("#add_cart").click(function() {
  $("#output").empty();
  $.each(checkedRows, function(index, value) {
    $('#output').append($('<li></li>').text(value.id + " | " + value.name + " | " + value.forks));
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.8.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.8.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<table id="eventsTable"
       data-toggle="table"
       data-height="300"
       data-url="https://api.github.com/users/wenzhixin/repos?type=owner&sort=full_name&direction=asc&per_page=100&page=1"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-search="true"
       data-show-refresh="true"
       data-show-toggle="true"
       data-show-columns="true"
       data-toolbar="#toolbar">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th data-field="name">Name</th>
        <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
        <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
        <th data-field="description">Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<button id="add_cart">Add to card</button>
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

Comment: That's great, perfect.

Comment: Hi, It is posible to set this code (show only selected items) to work with a normal table (data source to be from html, not from JSON)?   Sorry, I don't know JS. Thank you for any help.

Comment: @Tudor It shouldn't make any difference if the data is static HTML or coming from JSON. Did you try it out ?

Comment: Yes. My problem is that I can't manage to do that from JS for this sniped: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/bypbqboe/64/) . Can you please help?

Comment: how do you get values of all items if you check box all?

Comment: Link (https://bootstrap-table.com/examples/#events) in the answer is not working anymore.

Comment: More elegant in 2020: `.on('uncheck.bs.table', function (e, row) {
        checkedRows = checkedRows.filter(item => item.id != row.id)
      });`

Comment: Not working when check the page global check for all visible elements. Best use $('#id').bootstrapTable('getSelections');

Answer (score 9):

To get the selected (checked) rows, use [getSelections](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/methods/#getselections) method.

Note that if you are using pagination, then you have to use the [maintainMetaData](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#maintainmetadata) table option.

Here is an example which displays selected product's names when user clicks on *Show Selected Rows* button:

```js
var $table = $('#myTable');

function getRowSelections() {
  return $.map($table.bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function(row) {
    return row;
  })
}

$('#showSelectedRows').click(function() {
  var selectedRows = getRowSelections();
  var selectedItems = '\n';
  $.each(selectedRows, function(index, value) {
    selectedItems += value.name + '\n';
  });

  alert('The following products are selected: ' + selectedItems);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<div id="toolbar">
  <button id="showSelectedRows" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Show Selected Rows</button>
</div>

<table id="myTable" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-toggle="table" data-maintain-meta-data="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
      <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
      <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Product Name</th>
      <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Chair</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Sofa</td>
      <td>$500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Desk</td>
      <td>$300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Rug</td>
      <td>$200</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This to me is a much cleaner solution and works perfectly

Comment: Awesome solution,  it's clean and uses the own bootstrap table methods, works great!

Comment: @hooman is this works for server side pagination?

Comment: @Rahul: of course not, JavaScript works on the frontend

Answer (score 2):

Here is example give it to you :

**HTML**

```
<table id="table-style">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>

<button>Add to cart</button>
```

**JS**

```
var arr;
$('button').click(function(){
  arr = $('#table-style').find('[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
      return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
  }).get();

  console.log(arr);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/mvcf2brc/1/)**

Comment: sorry your solution doesn't matching for me, the table takes data from data-url="tables/data2.json" and check-boxes are automatically taken by bootstrap. Then how can I get Item ID value if checked particular?

Comment: Do you try already? Doesn't matter where the data came from and what important is at end of how DOM rendered your data into page. Inspect element on table then copy it structure then paste it in here for more specified solution

Comment: yse I'm uses this only

Comment: @Vg. See DavidDomain answer. Those plugin have their own event function for that.

Comment: Thanks for taking efforts, DavidDomain's answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap table has a function getSelections

with the javascript funciton you can get all selected rows. (your checkobx fiels should be bound to data-field="state")

```
            function getIdSelections() {
            return $.map($table.bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {
                return row.Id
            });
        }
```