# How to get complete data from (html) bootstrap table when pagination is turned on

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, bootstrap-table

I am using [bootstrap table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/) in my web page and want to get complete textual data from all table cells, when pagination is on. I have tried the following method and it returns all the data:

```
var data = $('#' + tableID).bootstrapTable('getData')
```

Now when i traverse `data` object to get value for every cell it works fine but, for those cells which have some nested html , for example:

```
   <td class="danger">cell 4</td>
   <td>
   <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a>
   </td>
```

Now, in this case, i want to get value for second cell as **google** but it returns me whole html as

```
 <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a>
```

Any idea, how i can get only textual value.

I can't do any server side operation, I have to achieve this using javascript/jquery. I have also tried using jquery:

```
function getColData(tableID,colIndex) {
    var colArray = $('#' + tableID + ' td:nth-child'+'('+colIndex+')').map(function(){
           return $(this).text();
       }).get();
       return colArray
    }
```

it returns data correctly but only which is visible on active page and i want all the data.

Comment: can you please add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/7373/, I added sample code and the data is shown in alert. I am unable to traverse it properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134884/getting-values-of-selected-table-rows-in-bootstrap-using-jquery

Comment: have you seen this?

Comment: not really, but it also doesn't work as it involves row click event which sends the row object internally from table, but not in my case, Here i have updated code, you can see:
http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/7379/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the actual data is coming in as a string, I don't think bootstrap-table can't differentiate it from the other data. The simple solution I can think of is to use `substring()` to extract the data from the cells that contain custom html.

http://jsfiddle.net/vwg5Lefz/

The alternative is to go through the generated table `<td>` and use `text()` to get the text data from the cells.

http://jsfiddle.net/n0djy60v/

Comment: Second solution is not an option because it doesn't return complete data in case pagination is turned on.

First solution is okay but not very elegant because it can break if i have nested tags inside cell, However, i think this is only feasible choice i have, i think i can generalise portion of code to find textual content inside cell by removing all the tags.

Thanks !

Comment: No problem, I realize it's not exactly the solution but if I spot a more elegant solution similar to what you're looking for in a future update for the plugin, I'll be sure to update my answer. :)

Comment: I'm looking for something equivalent to the second solution that would return all rows (even those that the pagination hides). Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your file on JSFiddle I have modified the JS part as follows, this will get you the text on every td(i.e. text or text content) and not the values of their attributes. Basically this traverses through the DOM searching for  tags embedded in  ones - except for those on the table header - then obtains the text value.

```
var table = $('#table'), button = $('#button');
button.click(function() {
  var data = [];
  table.find('tr:not(:first)').each(function(i, row) {
    var cols = [];
    $(this).find('td').each(function(i, col) {
      cols.push($(this).text());
    });
    data.push(cols);
  });
  alert(data);
});
```

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/7436/)

**UPDATE:**
This will get you all data regardless of pagination, also it will strip tags and nested tags.

```
var table = $('#table'), button = $('#button');

button.click(function() {
  var messedData = table.bootstrapTable('getData');
  var data = [];
  $.each(messedData, function(i, row) {
    var rowData = {
      'name': row['0'],
      'star': row['1'],
      'forks': row['2'],
      'desc': row['3'],
    }

    for (prop in rowData) {
      var tmp = document.createElement("div");
      tmp.innerHTML = rowData[prop];
      rowData[prop] = tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
    }

    data.push(rowData);
  });
  console.log(data);
});
```

You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4qorjmx2/8/)

Comment: Hey, Thanks but this code will not work in case pagination is turned on, So any solution traversing DOM is not an option because I need to get complete data irrespective of pagination on or off.
You can see here, select 5 records per page and then click, records are missing because Dom object are not there for invisible pages.
http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/7447/

Comment: @TechMaster I do have the same need. Have you found a solution?